# Simulator на Xcode 10 стал ужасно тормозить

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

На Xcode 9 все работало идеально и быстро. После обновления Xcode до 10 версия анимация в симуляторе стала просто ужасно тормозной, около 2 fps при простейшей анимации. На любом стандартном приложении также (не только в моем проекте), при переключении приложений, в общем абсолютно любая анимация. Кто-нибудь сталкивался или может предложить решение?

Comment: А какая версия OS, полный номер?

Comment: Mac OS 10.13.6. iOS на симуляторах 12.0, установил старые симуляторы с 11.4 — не помогает, тоже лагают ужасно. До обновления работали идеально.

Comment: По-моему, дело в High Sierra. Мне показалось, что 10.13.5 еще работала нормально, после обновления до 10.13.6 начались торможения.

Comment: Попробуйте запускать на симуляторе iPhone SE, он побыстрее.

Comment: Ок, попробуем. У вас тоже тормозит на .6? Подождем выхода 10.14, может там все гуд...

Comment: Угу, подтормаживает. Mojave уже кстати давно доступен, еще с беты, попробуйте, отпишитесь потом )

Comment: Да не хочется как-то бету ставить, все-равно потом переустанавливать. Через 4 дня отпишусь, когда релиз уже будет))

Comment: Попробовал по советам это: defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint X, с параметрами 1, 2, 3. Ничего не менялось...

Answer (score 0):

В меню эмулятора необходимо убрать галочку по пути: **Debug -> Slow Animations**.

Вероятно вы могли случайно нажать эту комбинацию клавиш.

Comment: Нет, это совершенно не то. Анимация не медленная. Она тормозит, пропуская кадры. Выходит 2-4 fps. При настройке медленной анимации она медленная, но фреймрейт все-равно высокий и не тормозит.